# XNA, winform and full screen

Tags: c#, winforms, xna

I have integrated XNA and winform with this tutorial http://roy-t.nl/index.php/2008/10/09/xna-30-and-winforms-the-easy-way/ the problem is that I would like be able to view the content XNA in full screen. How do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to resize content in picturebox you will need to add event `SizeChanged`
in which you will update BackBuffer width and height.Otherwise rendering output will become pixalated.

```
 PresentationParameters params;
 params.BackBufferWidth = control.ClientSize.Width;
 params.BackBufferHeight = control.ClientSize.Height;
 GraphicDevice.Reset(params);
```